# Facebook JS-SDK Not working properly if called in iframe with Firefox and Edge

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

If we using Facebook JS SDK for login and call it from iframe - it's not working in Firefox and Chrome. I mean if the script of facebook and button are in an iframe

First of all, with debug.js we can see that responses from Facebook are different for Firefox and Chrome i.e.

In Firefox and Edge we getting flag 'registred' which set up in 'canvas' which I guess wrong. Example of response: 
**received message _FB_f132xxxxxxae6logged_in=true&registered=canvas&xd_action=proxy_ready from https://staticxx.facebook.com**

And after a click on 'Login with Facebook' no popup or new iframe opening in Firefox or Edge, what I believe happening because of 'canvas' flag.

Fun thing - that if we are changing the user agent in a browser - everything works properly.

And of course if in Firefox we move login button to mainframe - everything ok.

I cant provide my site cause IP blocking, but for example, TripAdvisor has the same problem https://www.tripadvisor.com/ if you will try to sign in with Facebook. Because they have a button in an iframe.

I will appreciate any guesses and help

Comment: Are we talking iframe with content loaded from a different domain than the parent page? Browsers are getting stricter in their default blocking of 3rd-party cookies, easily imaginable that this is interfering here.

Comment: @04FS Nope, domain is same. Also I disabled all Content Security Polices at Firefox and still dont working

Comment: Hm, dunno then. If changing the UA makes it work, then I’d guess the SDK itself contains code to treat different browsers differently. You could file a bug report with Facebook, but not sure how much of a priority they’d give this, seems to be a rather special situation. Why does this have to be in an iframe to begin with, can’t you find some other way of handling this?

Comment: @04FS I have to wait 24h after registration to report bug on Facebook Developers - what a system :)

Yeah, seems like some logic around there. 

There a lot of login logic at iframe and I cant easy change it, so I'm looking for easy solution :)